# C++-How to append a character to a certain position in a string?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that i have to do that indicates i have to find the vowels in a string and the character next to the vowel has to be added to the string as an underscore. ex: hello > he_llo_ but I have been able to find the vowels and replace the character to the right of the vowel in a way so that hello > he_lo ... any help is greatly appreciated.this is what I have done so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
bool checkVowel(char ch)
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
    if(ch=='a'|| ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u'||ch=='y')
{
return true;
}
return false;
};
int main()
{
string str;
getline (cin,str);
for(size_t i=0;i<str.size();++i)
{
if(isvowel(str[i]))
{
str[i+1]='_';
}
};
cout<< str<<"\n";
};
```

Comment: So what is it doing wrong? Overwriting the next char instead of appending after the vowel? That's the problem you need to fix...

Comment: You mean like [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)?

Comment: Yes thank you I tried insert previously but always threw a char to const char* error zenith helped me figure it out

Answer (score 2):

[`std::string::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/)

For example:

```
if(isvowel(str[i]))
{
    str.insert(i+1, "_");
}
```

Or:

```
if(isvowel(str[i]))
{
    str.insert(i+1, 1, '_');
}
```